# SPEL doesn't work with 'in' operator for collections inside an object

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-el

```
@Query("select distinct product from Product product where :#{#activeFilters.flowerSorts} is null or product.name in :#{#filters.names}")
Set<Product> findAllForFilter(Filters filters);
```

```
public class Filters {
    private Set<String> names;
}
```

[image]

[image]

> 2023-09-19 12:02:17.183  WARN 6316 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] .m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected AST node: {vector} [select distinct product from ...

Hello, I'm trying to execute query with several elements in my collections. However it doesn't work, but it does with single elements.

Comment: Please add the complete stacktrace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is in query syntax:

You should have next one `@Query` body

```
@Query("select distinct product from Product product where product.name in (:#{#filters.names})")
Set<Product> findAllForFilter(Filters filters);
```

**Update**

It should generated something like this:

```
from Product product where product.name in (?, ?…)
```

But I am not sure in it, I need to test it. As solution you also can write the query in this one way:

```
@Query("select distinct product from Product product where product.name in (:filters)")
    Set<Product> findAllForFilter(@Param(“filters”) Set<String> filters);
```

And when you are going to invoke the method you will pass a Set of strings aka filters, I think it is better than SPEL

Comment: I did the same thing. Does it ever possible to do such trick? I mean, get collection from an object and put it into query?

Comment: I just made an update to  the answer about it, can you check ?

Comment: Thanks, the first solution works, however It doesn't work if I put condition `:#{#filters.names} is null` into the query. And I fixed it with wrapping it into brackets: 

`(:#{#activeFilters.flowerSorts}) is null`